# Stripes - redirect, expire session

Tags: java, stripes

I have a Stripes framework question.

This redirect page in the annotation method before?

something like:

```
@Before
public void test()
{
  String login=(String)context.getRequest().getSession().getAttribute("login");
  if (login==null)
  {
    Redirect...(LoginActionBean.class);  // ??????
    exit....();                                    // ??????
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you try to do something like this:

```
public class MyPageActionBean implements ActionBean {
  private ActionBeanContext context;

  public ActionBeanContext getContext() {
    return context;
  }

  public void setContext(ActionBeanContext context) {
    this.context = context;
  }

  @DefaultHandler
  public Resolution view() {
    String login =
      (String)context.getRequest().getSession().getAttribute("login");
    if (login==null) {
      return new RedirectResolution(LoginActionBean.class);
    } else {
      // do you're normal stuff here
    }
  }
}
```

But a more complete security solution would be to implement the [Stripes Security Interceptor](http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Security+Interceptor+for+custom+authorization).

Answer (score 0):

Hm. This isnt nice.

Duplication code in all method.

```
public Resolution view1()
{
  String login=....
  if () {...}
  else  {...}
}

public Resolution view2()
{
  String login=....
  if () {...}
  else  {...}
}
public Resolution view3()
{
  String login=....
  if () {...}
  else  {...}
}
```

So, i go read Stripes Security Interceptor.

Thanks.

Comment: You can of course also write your own interceptor: http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Intercept+Execution (it's very easy!)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is to redirect a user on login page when they are not logged in. Using **@before** on each actionBean is not a good idea. To achieve this you can make your own interceptor by extending SpringInterceptorSupport.

```
@Intercepts(LifecycleStage.ActionBeanResolution)
public class MyInterceptor extends SpringInterceptorSupport {
private static final List<Class<? extends ActionBean>> ALLOW = Arrays.asList(LoginActionBean.class, anyOtherActionBeanAllowedWithoutLogin.class);

@Override
  @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes" })
  public Resolution intercept(ExecutionContext execContext) throws Exception {
    Resolution resolution = execContext.proceed();
    ActionBean actionBean = execContext.getActionBean();
    Class<? extends ActionBean> destinationclass = actionBean.getClass();
    if (!ALLOW.contains(destinationclass) && !isSessionExist()) {
      resolution = new RedirectResolution(LoginActionBean.class);
    }
    return resolution;

  }

  private boolean isSessionExist() {
    String login = (String)context.getRequest().getSession().getAttribute("login");
    return login != null;
  }

}
```